# WCF and one function to rule them all?

Tags: .net, wcf, architecture

It's an architectural question.

We have a client-server situation. We want to get rid of remote desktop solutions (like Citrix, Propalms, etc...). And SOA seems like the solution. We can't use direct SQL connections because of the security.

So we make a WCF webservice with one function that can take a query (as a string) as parameter and then returns a string with the result of that query. All our software will simply call this function by throwing in queries (as strings) and awaiting the results (which are strings).

The client exe knows what this result looks like because it made the call, so let the client exe worry about that. To be specific, it'll be a piece of XML which will describe the columns and the rows with data that the query returns. And because it's all our own software we agree internally on the format of the XML.

My question is: Do you guys foresee any issues with this solution?

Comment: What does this have to do with remote desktops? Are you having people doing this manually today?

Comment: This method seems just like another communication layer that wraps the data. The data still needs to be parsed, so why add another "virtual" layer that serves no purpose?

Comment: I'v updated my original post which should answer your questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This approach is called "overly-generic interface", and is an anti-pattern.

This approach avoids almost all the benefits that WCF gives you: formatting/parsing, versioning, lifetime management, and interception (for things like semantic logging). It also prevents discoverability (IntelliSense) and compile-time checking for client code, and encourages magic strings on the client and a god object design on the server. Also, working with full strings that themselves must be encoded into the actual messages adds overhead.

There aren't any real benefits to that approach. There are some things that *seem* like benefits - like the ability to change the API without recompiling clients. But those are actually drawbacks: if the API changes, you *want* clients depending on the old API to break, so you know they need to change.

Comment: First off, you are absolutely right ofcourse. I'm looking for input to take with me in a discussion we have internally about our future. The benefits my superior is looking for is performance: exactly what is needed across the wire. And he's afraid that developers will make a mess of the API.